# how to solve the errors of this program

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

#include <cstring>

void initialize(char[],int*);
void input(const char[] ,int&);
void print ( const char*,const  int);
void growOlder (const char [], int* );

bool comparePeople(const char* ,const int*,const char*,const int*);

int main(){

     char name1[25];
     char name2[25];
     int age1;  
     int age2;


    initialize (name1,&age1);
    initialize (name2,&age2);

    print(name1,*age1);
    print(name2,*age2);

    input(name1,age1);
    input(name2,age2);

    print(&name1,&age1);
    print(&name2,&age2);

    growOlder(name2,age2);

    if(comparePeople(name1,&age1,name2,&age2))
    cout<<"Both People have the same  name and age "<<endl;
    return 0;
}

void input(const char name[],int &age)
{
    cout<<"Enter a name :";
    cin>>name ;

    cout<<"Enter an age:";
    cin>>age;
    cout<<endl;
}

void initialize (  char name[],int *age)
{  
name="";
age=0;
}
void print ( const char name[],const int age )
{
    cout<<"The Value stored in variable name is :"
         <<name<<endl
        <<"The Value stored in variable  age is :"
         <<age<<endl<<endl;
}

void growOlder(const char name[],int *age)
{
    cout<< name <<" has grown one year older\n\n";
    *age++;
}
bool comparePeople (const char *name1,const int *age1,
                    const char *name2,const int *age2)
{

    return(age1==age2 &&strcmp(name1,name2));

}
```

Comment: Please edit your post to make better use of the code formatting. It is difficult to read otherwise.

Comment: Please don't just post a ambiguous title and source code, it's common courtesy to provide information on the error and the context of the code.

Comment: Mr pez cuckow, I'm new in this website and Idon't know every thing  . so , if you can copy this and paste it to your visual studio program ,and see the errors.

Comment: Which is why they're telling you - so that you'll be less new the next time you post. A lot of it boils down to a common courtesy - we want to see that you've taken the time to lay out the problem nicely, and have narrowed to as far as you can *before* asking for help. Then, when someone shows you the answer, since you put time into it, hopefully, you'll remember it, and learn something. It's less fun for the answerers if you don't take something (other than the answer) away from here.

Answer (score 1):

Oh dear. The more I look at this code, the harder it is to find a line without some bug or another. My original comments (containing specific bugs I found) are still at the bottom of this post, but this code is crying out for drastic refactoring:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Since you say you're using visual studio, presumably you're coding in C++.
// People is a perfect candidate for a class:

class Person
{
  private:
    // Instead of char arrays, you should use std::string for string data
    string name;
    int age;

  public:
    // The initialize() method becomes the class constructor
    Person() : name(""), age(0) {}

    void growOlder()
    {
      cout << name << " has grown one year older\n\n";
      age++;
    }

    // Instead of comparePeople, you can overload operator==
    bool operator==(const Person &other) const
    {
      return age == other.age && name == other.name;
    }

    void print() const
    {
      cout << "The value stored in variable name is: " << name << endl;
    }

    // A factory method can construct a Person from imput
    static Person input()
    {
      Person p;
      cout << "Enter a name: " << endl;
      cin >> p.name;
      cout << "Enter an age: " << endl;
      cin >> p.age;
      return p;
    }
};

int main()
{
  Person p1 = Person::input();
  Person p2 = Person::input();

  p1.print();
  p2.print();

  p2.growOlder();

  if(p1 == p2)
  {
    cout << "Both people have the same name and age" << endl;
    return 0;
  }
}
```

**Original remarks:**

A couple of bugs I noticed on a quick reading:

```
void initialize ( char name[],int *age) {name=""; age=0; }
```

should be

```
void initialize ( char name[],int *age) {name[0]='\0'; *age=0; }
```

and

```
return(age1==age2 &&strcmp(name1,name2));
```

should be

```
return(*age1==*age2 && !strcmp(name1,name2));
```

Also, this doesn't make any sense:

```
print(&name1,&age1);
print(&name2,&age2);
```

Comment: first, Ihave n't studied class till now.
so, If you can solve it by using arrays and pointers.
I will appericate that.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:
1.  Use `std::string` instead of 'char *`.
This relieves you of many headaches such as memory allocation and resizing.  (Input and output is also simpler.)

2. If the argument to a function will be modified, pass by reference (don't use pointers).
   C++ provides **references** which allow a variable to be modified without the mess of pointers.  References don't need to be checked for NULL and very seldom do they point to something illegal or missing.
   Example:

   void intialize(std::string& name, int& age)
   {
     name.clear();
     age = 0;
     return;
   }
3. Start using classes, structures and objects.  Let the objects handle input, output and comparison:
   struct Person
   {
   std::string name;  // Every person has a name.
   unsigned int age;  // An "age" cannot be negative, so it is declared as unsigned.

   Person() // Default constructor
   :  age(0)  // Use initialization list for initializations.
   { ; }      // String will initialize itself, so not listed here.

   void Print(void)  // Prints the members using std::cout.
   {
    cout << "Name: \"" << name << "\"\n";
    cout << "Age:  " << age << "\n";
    return;
   };

To print a person:

```
Person me;
me.name = "Albert Einstein";
me.age = 53;
me.Print();
```

Encapsulating the `Print` functionality inside the `struct` helps to simplify the program.  No need for all those C-style functions.